# Convert single line RSA private ssh key to multi line

Tags: encryption, ssh, openssl, rsa

I have these private keys that have been converted to single line equivalent.

These keys are quite a lot.

So I decided to invest some time to write a script to convert.

This has not yielded to much.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4= pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4= pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4= pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4= pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4= -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am using `echo ~/.ssh/id_rsa | tr " " "\n"`

This returns:

```
-----BEGIN 
RSA 
PRIVATE 
KEY----- 
pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=
pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=
pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=
pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=
pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=pEdInVAbH4d0PH4=
-----END
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
```

I have been trying to figure out the best possible way to get this back to the right format.

Comment: LOL, you just use the PEM encoder / decoder in C# that I haven't published yet. Seriously though, this is a standard OpenSSL / PEM format, it's not SSH specific.

Comment: Uh, whoever wrote that RSA private key buggered up completely, that's not a single base64 line, it's probably just the components all base64 encoded seperately. It's also missing a dash in the pre-encapsulation boundary (i.e. header line).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I assume it's just dummy characters because OP doesn't want to disclose their private key.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming a standard RSA private key that just had the newlines removed, a couple of `sed` replacements will get you back to the original format:

```
sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/"\
    -e "s/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/\n&/"\
    -e "s/\S\{64\}/&\n/g"\
    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The standard key format requires the `BEGIN` and `END` statements to be on a separate line, and the base64-encoded key to be formatted at 64 columns. The above command will get you there.

Comment: @WilliamRoss Best guess: you don't have the same begin stanza as the one in my code (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`). Maybe yours has `BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY` or `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`. Or maybe you deleted a hyphen by accident at some point...

Comment: @WilliamRoss Is removing your comment your way of indicating that my guess was correct, and your issue is solved?

Answer (score 3):

@robby Thanks from your answer I adapted the following which worked for me.

```
sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/" -e "s/\S\{64\}/&\n/g" | sed "s/^\s//g" ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu and worked. But not on MacBook

Comment: you need to install GNU sed in mac with for example `brew install gnu-sed` and then use `gsed` instead of `sed`

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the solution to **ed25519 algorithm** to talk to Gitlab via SSH. Thanks @Robby!

```
RUN sed -i -e "s/-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/"\
    -e "s/-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----/\n&/"\
    -e "s/\S\{70\}/&\n/g"\
    /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Input

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX== -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE 
KEY-----
```

Output

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```